# Storm InvalidTopologyException

Tags: apache-storm

I'm getting an error message when I try to run my topology:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
... 
Caused by: InvalidTopologyException(msg:Component: [write] subscribes from non-existent stream: [default] of component [write])
```

Here's my topology declaration:

```
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("spout", spout, 1);
    builder.setBolt("write", new PrinterBolt(), 1).shuffleGrouping("write");
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

In your spout declaration `shuffleGrouping("write")` refers to the source stream of the printer bolt. In this case, it's saying to source from "write" component with the default stream id.

You must change it to `shuffleGrouping("spout")` to source from the "spout" component.